# Detect Line Break in the Text View

Tags: swift

I want to detect a line break in the `TextView` to replace it for some Unicode symbol. Is there any way to detect line break in swift? I want to replace each line break in the whole text.

Comment: line break is `\n`. delegate method is - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618630-textview

Comment: Are you referring to explicit newlines or are you referring to line breaks causing by word wrapping? Please [edit] your question and clarify what you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex to match line breaks and then replace them with what you want. Use `"""` for multiline text

```swift
let replacement = ","
let yourText = textView.text // your textview's text
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[\n]", options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)
let range = NSMakeRange(0, yourText.utf16.count)
let replacedString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: yourText, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: replacement)
print(replacedString) // will add commas instead of line breaks
```

[Live example](https://paiza.io/projects/hWNBCMnWVWF7wV5jlkGzpg?language=swift)

Comment: This is way more complicated than needed. Simply use `replacingOccurrences(id:with:)`. And the value you pass to the length parameter of `NSMakeRange` is wrong. It needs to be `yourText.utf16.count`.

Comment: You are right @rmaddy any idea how can we replace line breaks with replacingOccurrences ?

Comment: You can't. You can replace newlines, but not line breaks since line breaks are just formatting.

Comment: @rmaddy well, I think that the OP mentioned _I want to detect a line break_ and then replace it with some entity So I think that my answer answers the question.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I looked for.